# unhashable type: 'dict_keys' -works in ver. 2.7.5 but not in 3.4

Tags: python, typeerror

I was coding something like this:
    `tmp1=tmp[tmp.keys()[0]]`

where: `tmp={'Freud':{3,6,9},'Sigmund':{6}} # a dictionary`

this piece of code works flawlessly in Python ver. 2.7
but if I run the same in ver. 3.4
I got a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'
how come?
how can I fix it in ver. 3.4?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right exception?  Shouldn't you be getting  `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`?   (It's usually a good idea to copy and paste a transcript, so that you're showing an error rather than describing it.)

Comment: that's the whole message (running it at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php)... after the traceback... the TypeError is:  unhashable type: 'dict_keys'

Comment: Nope: you get the indexing error.  Did you type `tmp[tmp.keys()]` instead?  That would give the error you're reporting.

Answer (score 14):

Replace:

```
tmp1=tmp[tmp.keys()[0]]
```

With:

```
tmp1=tmp[list(tmp.keys())[0]]
```

#### Discussion

In python3, as opposed to python2, `keys` returns an iterable set-like view object, not a list.  For example:

```
>>> tmp.keys()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

But:

```
>>> list(tmp.keys())[0]
'Freud'
```

Comment: Not an iterator but an iterable set-like view object, which will reflect changes on the underlying dict.

Comment: @achampion OK.  Answer updated with the longer more precise wording.

Answer (score 3):

Python3 defaulted to using view objects for accessing dicts, if you change the underlying dictionary the view object reflects the change.
For your case you can simply do:

```
tmp1 = tmp[list(tmp)[0]]
```

However this can be quite expensive. If all you need is any element from the dictionary then you could do:

```
tmp1 = tmp[next(iter(tmp))]
```

which avoids the cost of constructing the key list.

Comment: Nice tip,, and thanks for your response mr... I need to look into the "next(iter(tmp)" thing thou... I come from the ver 2.4....

Comment: `iter(tmp)` creates an iterator from tmp. `next(iterator)` gets the next item from that iterator. This is effectively happening behind the scenes when you write `for t in tmp:`